# Laravel password expired, class does not exist

Tags: laravel

I want to build in an expiry of passwords onto my website. I came across [a very helpful document](https://laraveldaily.com/password-expired-force-change-password-every-30-days/) which is very good. However on my local PC this does not work, the reset of password does not appear.

But when I transfer all to the website, I get the error

> Class `app\Http\Requests\PasswordExpiredRequest` does not exist

The class has been created and is in the correct path. Please assist, where have I missed something

Comment: run `composer du` to reload classes

Comment: Have you run **composer dump-autoload** command ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure the contents of `app/Http/Requests/PasswordExpiredRequest.php` are:

```
<?php

namespace App/Http/Requests;

class PasswordExpiredRequest extends FormRequest
{

    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'current_password' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
        ];
    }
}
```

(the document forgot to mention adding  the namespace to the file)